# re.search is not returning complete match

Tags: pandas, python-re

I have dataframe with multiple columns of text. In one column with text I try to search for a substring with wildcards in a long string and put the result in a new column. The problem is that I manage to find a result, but the match is not returning the complete string.

For example I have this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Col1': ['Some data 1', 'Some data 2', 'Some data 3'],
        'Col2': ['More data 1', 'More data 2', 'More data 3'],
        'Text': ['ID:12345;Description: This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for;Status=off;',
                    'Description: This is a another long piece of text containting some different information I want to search for;ID:abcde;Status=on;',
                    'Status=unknown;ID:abcde;Description: And this is a third piece of long piece of text which I want to search for;']
    }
)
```

What I tried is this:

```
df['Description'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: re.search('Description: (.*?);',x))
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
Col1    Col2    Text    Description
0   Some data 1 More data 1 ID:12345;Description: This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for;Status=off;    <re.Match object; span=(9, 101), match='Description: This is a long piece of text contain>
1   Some data 2 More data 2 Description: This is a another long piece of text containting some different information I want to search for;ID:abcde;Status=on;   <re.Match object; span=(0, 110), match='Description: This is a another long piece of text>
2   Some data 3 More data 3 Status=unknown;ID:abcde;Description: And this is a third piece of long piece of text which I want to search for;    <re.Match object; span=(24, 112), match='Description: And this is a third piece of long pi>
```

It seems like the re.Match object is cutting of the result since I am expecting a longer match.
Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.

You are seeing the "repr" of the match object, which doesn't display the full data.

```
text = 'ID:12345;Description: This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for;Status=off;'

print(re.search(r'Description: (.*?);', text))

# <re.Match object; span=(9, 101), match='Description: This is a long piece of text contain>
```

If you access the actual data match e.g. with `.group(1)` you can see it's there:

```
print(re.search(r'Description: (.*?);', text).group(1))

# 'This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for'
```

Similarly with pandas (note: pandas has re methods under [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract))

```
df['Text'].str.extract(r'Description: (.*?);')

#                                                    0
# 0  This is a long piece of text containting some ...
# 1  This is a another long piece of text containti...
# 2  And this is a third piece of long piece of tex...
```

```
df['Text'].str.extract(r'Description: (.*?);').iloc[0]

# 0    This is a long piece of text containting some ...
# Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The match is actually there:

```
df['Text'].str.extract(r'Description: (.*?);').iloc[0].item()

# 'This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for'
```

To see everything at once - it could help to output the result with `.to_csv()`, or `.to_json()` e.g.

```
print(df['Text'].str.extract(r'Description: (.*?);').to_json(indent=4))
```

```
{
    "0":{
        "0":"This is a long piece of text containting some information I want to search for",
        "1":"This is a another long piece of text containting some different information I want to search for",
        "2":"And this is a third piece of long piece of text which I want to search for"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also wasn't aware of the "df.str.extract" functions which definitely helps me avoiding the lambda function!